# Date Picker Java script is working in my local but not in main environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle11g, datepicker, weblogic

I have a code for masking future dates in date picker which masks the dates of the future month exactly after one month from current month. eg: if today is 12/16/2015 future dates visible will be end date of january 2016 i.e 01/31/2016. All other future dates are masked.

Now this code is working in my local and i am able to select 01/31/2016 and all the future dates after 01/31/2016 are blank which is exactly working. Now when it is deployed to the main server environment, i am able to select till 01/30/2016. 01/31/2016 is not selectable.

is this anykind of javascript problem which is not working on this main server as they are different servers? Please help.Thanks

Below is the code:

```
/* 
 * This method is the same as getCalendarOnClick(...) above, except that when  
 * future months are allowed, the maximum End Date allowed is the last day of 
 * the future month. 
 * Example - If the current date is 08/15/2006, and maxFutureMonths is set to 1, 
 * the maximum End Date allowed will be 09/30/2006. 
 */
 private String getMonthEndDateCalendarOnClick(
      String formName,
      String fieldName,
      boolean synthetic,
      boolean allowFutureDates,
      int maxFutureMonths )
 {
      String calendarScript = "civCalendar.fshowCalendar( '"
           + formName
           + "."
           + fieldName
           + "', new Date ( 1900, 0, 1 ), new Date( ";

      if ( !allowFutureDates )
      {
           //Only show dates up to the current date
           calendarScript = calendarScript
                + System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
      else if ( maxFutureMonths == 0 )
      {
           //show all dates
           calendarScript = calendarScript
                + "2199, 11, 31";
      }
      else
      {
           Date futureDate = new Date();
           futureDate.addMonths( maxFutureMonths );
           futureDate = DateUtility.getMonthEndDate( futureDate );  

           long futureDateInMilliseconds = futureDate.asMilliseconds();

           calendarScript = calendarScript
                + futureDateInMilliseconds;
      }

      if ( synthetic )
      {
           calendarScript = calendarScript
                + " ), true );return false;";
      }
      else
      {
           calendarScript = calendarScript
                + " ) );return false;";
      }

      return calendarScript;

 }
```

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue

Comment: As you've shown no code I can only guess

Comment: I have added code now. Please check

well the thing is my program doesnot look for day. It checks the current month and counts one month from current month and masks the future dates. For Eg: For all dates in Dec 2015, calender allows to select till last day of january, that means for dates between 12/01/2015 to 12/31/2015, i should be able to select dates till 01/31/2016. As i said i am able to select 31st jan in local but not on main server